# Ajax: Get a ID value of a DropdownList

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

For a project, I must be able to assign a user to a group, this must be done in ASP MVC with ajax.

So I have a datatable that displays users, and above, I have a DropdownList that contains the different groups possible (you will find a screenshot below).
When the user clicks the group in the DropdownList, the datatable displays all the users in the group.

This works very well.

My problem is here:
Each user has a button 'Deasign' which allows to disassemble the user of the group.
My problem is to get the id of the group linked to the group name of this DropdownList (it displays the name of the group), then pass it as a parameter and send it in a POST of my API.

I am stuck and do not know how to recover this value, would you have an idea? I am new to ajax.

Dropdownlist:

```
             @*Dropdownlist Group*@
         $('#GroupDropDown').change(function () {
             var table = $('#UsersDatatables').DataTable();
             table.destroy();
             var id = $('#GroupDropDown').val();

             // Permet que quand le user cliquer sur Display All, cela affiche la table complète
             var SelectValue = $('#GroupDropDown option:selected').text();

             if (SelectValue == "   Display All  ")
                 GetDatatable();
             else {
                 $('#UsersDatatables').DataTable({
                     processing: true,
                     ajax: {
                         url: "/User/GetUsersinGroup/" + id,
                         type: "GET",
                         datatype: "json",
                         data: { idGroup: id },
                         error: function (error) {
                             toastr.error("No users found.");
                         }

                     },
                     columns: [
                         { data: "USE_FirstName" },
                         { data: "USE_LastName" },
                         { data: "USE_Gender" },
                         { data: "Country" },
                         { data: "USE_PhoneNumber" },
                         { data: "USE_EmailAddress" },
                         {
                             data: "USE_Id", "render": function (data) {
                                     return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" id="' + data + '">Edit</a> <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm deasign" id="' + data + '">Deassign</a>';
                             },
                             orderable: false,
                             width: "150px"
                         },
                     ],
                 })
             }
         })
```

Function to Deassign a group

```
         function PostDeAssignGroup() {
         $('#UsersDatatables').on('click', '.deasign', function (e) {

             idGroup = $("GroupDown").val().DropDownListOnChange.

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 datatype: "json",
                 url: "http://localhost/api/User/DeAssignGroup/" + UserName + idGroup + id,
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data === "success") {
                         UsersDatatables.destroy();
                         toastr.success("The user has been successfully removed from the group.");
                     }
                 },
                 error: function (error) {
                     toastr.error("The user could not be deleted from the group.");
                 }

             })
         })
     }
```

My Controller method:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [Route("DeAssignGroup/{UserName}/{idGroup}/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult DeAssignGroup(string UserName , int idGroup, int id)
    {

        var Grpe = contexteEF.Group.Where(x => x.GRO_Id == idGroup).FirstOrDefault();
        if (Grpe == null)
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        try
        {

                var Use = contexteEF.User.Where(x => x.USE_Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (Use == null)
                    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

                User_Group ug = contexteEF.User_Group.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UGR_GRO_Id == idGroup && x.UGR_USE_Id == id);

                contexteEF.User_Group.Remove(ug);

            contexteEF.SaveChanges();

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

[I also leave a screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO4lf.png)

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Assuming the option `value` attribute has the `Id`, you can do `var id = $("#YourDropDownId").val()`

Comment: First thing first. You have an event (`click`) inside a function (`PostDeAssignGroup`).  Which is not needed at all. Just register a click event to an element.

Comment: Thanks for your advance, but how can i get the id of the group? Since the dropdownlist displays the name of the group? I'm in a User controller(i have a nother for groups)

Comment: @bipen -> correct me if im wrong, but my onclick serve when i click on '.deasign' button right?

Comment: @Shyju, i've try this but it does not work. idGroup is 'undefined' :(